# Warum erstinkt man Lügen?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, expression

Am Wochenende haben wir [Mäxle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A4xchen) gespielt (das wohl in anderen Regionen Deutschlands *Meier* heißt – warum auch immer), und an einer Stelle habe ich einen Viererpasch zurückgewiesen mit den Worten:

> Das hast du doch *erstunken* und erlogen!

Gut, der Viererpasch war tatsächlich gelogen (es waren 42 oder 43, ist aber auch egal), aber ich habe mich dann gefragt, warum Lügen stinken, oder warum man sie erstinkt, zumal mir keine passende Volksschnelletymologie einfallen wollte. Weiß jemand Genaueres?

Comment: "er" hieß ursprünglich mal einfach etwas wie "aus". Die Lüge kommt also "aus" dir raus, genauso wie der Gestank. Ich denke, die schöpferische Komponente von "er-" könnte damals noch nicht so ausgeprägt gewesen sein. Die Idee, Gestank und schlechtes zu assoziieren findet sich nicht nur hier. "Der Stunk" ist "schlechte Stimmung", Ärger liegt "in der Luft", man kann "jemanden nicht riechen", und am ähnlichsten ist "Da ist etwas faul."

Comment: @Emanuel Interessantes Detail. Kann man bestimmt zu einer Antwort ausbauen …? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auch wenn es für eine Antwort etwas wenig sein mag: Aus [etymologie.info](http://www.etymologie.info/~e/d_/de-ade__e.html#Erstinken) lässt sich eine Theorie ableiten.
Das Wort *erstinken* bezeichnet demnach *etwas, das anfängt zu stinken*, insbesondere aufgrund einsetzender Fäulnis bzw. Verwesung. Etwas Erstunkenes ist also etwas, was schlecht ist. Diese Bedeutung scheint im fortlaufenden Sprachgebrauch auf weniger gegenständliche Bezüge übertragen worden zu sein.
Im konkreten Fall könnte man sagen, der Verfall der Ware (vgl. [Link](http://www.etymologie.info/~e/d_/de-ade__e.html#Erstinken)) dient als Analogie für den Verfall der moralischen Werte. (Hierbei unterstelle ich eine dem Lügen abgeneigte Philosophie.)
Jedoch kann ich zurzeit keine belastbaren Quellen für diese Theorie ausmachen.

Answer (score 6):

Das Wort »erstinken« scheint ursprünglich zwei sehr ähnliche Bedeutungen gehabt zu haben.

**Durch Gestank sterben**

> das vich ist *erstunchen* in sinem mist.

**Stinken nachdem man gestorben ist**

> da er (Lazarus) schon vier tag im grab gelegen und *erstunken* war.
>   gott der herr wolt den *erstunknen* Adam wider holen.

Aber schon Martin Luther benutzte das *Erstinken* als eine Verstärkung des Erlügens:

> also das es erlogen und erstunken ist, und Christo als einem lügner widerstrebt, wer da sagt, das die christenheit zu Rom oder an Rom gebunden sei.

Alle Zitate stammen aus dem [Wörterbuchnetz](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/call_wbgui_py_from_form?textpattern=erstunken&lemmapattern=&sigle=DWB&lemid=GE08861&mode=Volltextsuche).

Das Erstinken scheint den ekelerregenden Teil des Sterbens zu betonen und vermutlich hat Luther dieses Wort als Verstärkung des Erlügens verwendet, weil er damit zum Ausdruck bringen wollte, dass das Erfinden von Lügen ebenso abscheulich ist wie der Gestank des Todes.

Das ist jedoch nur eine Vermutung meinerseits. Quellen, die das bestätigen, habe ich nicht gefunden.

Comment: +1 für Wörterbuchnetz

Answer (score 1):

(1) Etwas zu erstinken bedeutet in dieser Verwendung offensichtlich analog zu *erfinden*, *erarbeiten*, *erschaffen*, *erzeugen*, *erlangen*, *erschleichen*, *erriechen*, *erraten*, *ersehen*, dass man es aus dem Nichts heraus schafft oder es sich aneignet. Mein Instinkt sagt mir, dass das Stinken sich hier eher auf das Endprodukt (die Lüge) bezieht, aber die analogen Verben legen eher nah, dass es Teil des Prozesses (des Lügens) ist.

Die andere Deutung als intransitives Verb analog zu *ertrinken*, *ersticken* passt hier offensichtlich schon semantisch nicht. (Formal würde es passen: Jemanden zu erstinken bedeutet offensichtlich, ihn durch Gestank zu töten.) Man beachte, dass man sich z.B. auch etwas ertrinken kann.

(2) Da das Verb *erstinken* fast ausschließlich in der Wendung *erstunken und erlogen* verwendet wird (früher allerdings gelegentlich auch in der Form *erlogen und erstunken*), liegt es auf der Hand, dass es sich um ein Wortspiel auf der Basis von *erfunden und erlogen* handelt. Seine Funktion besteht offensichtlich darin, der starken Betonung der Irrealität noch die Komponente der starken Missbilligung hinzuzufügen.

Answer (score 0):

Der Duden schreibt hierzu:

> ( salopp emotional: eine ganz bewusste, niederträchtige Lüge sein ;
>   erstunken ist 2. Partizip von veraltet erstinken = stinkend werden; 
>   also = stinkend geworden )

Das würde dann bedeuten: das ist nicht einfach nur gelogen, es ist so schlimm gelogen, daß es stinkt, also eine besonders unangenehme Lüge.